# Get actions/variables using a Bot with AIML

Tags: chatbot, aiml, pandorabots

I'm totally new to chatbots and I've started looking at AIML and Pandorabots with the idea of integrate its API to my App.

After some reading, I'm not sure if it's the best option. What I'd like to do is something like that (think as if my App was a book store):

```
Human: Show me the latests books.
Bot: Ok, here you can find the latest books.
```

What I'd like to get here as a response is also the action "show" and "latest" so the App will know what to do: Show a list of the latest books.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the OOB tag for doing so.

Like this:

```
<category>
    <pattern>SEARCH FOR *</pattern>
    <template>Here is what I found on Google. <oob><search><star/></search></oob></template>
</category>
```

For more info: https://medium.com/pandorabots-blog/using-oob-tags-in-aiml-part-i-21214b4d2fcd